# Ember Module Transpiler

Tags: javascript, ember.js, module, ember-cli

How does ember transpile modules? I understand that it doesn't use ember-cli-babel(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-babel#about-modules)
So where can I find details on ember's ES6 module transpiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up until ember-cli 1.13.8 it used this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-es6modules, which is a wrapper for the [esperanto](http://esperantojs.org/) library. You can see that in the package.json file here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/v1.13.8/package.json#L80

However, with ember-cli 1.13.9 it was indeed updated to use the [broccoli-babel-transpiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-babel-transpiler) package; see https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/v1.13.9/package.json#L72

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't see this as a dependency in the package.json file. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It uses babel now, it used to use this (up until ember-cli 1.13.8). Updated my answer.